# Problema com requisição ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, requisição

Estou com um problema com meu ajax, eu preciso fazer a verificação em outra página se um horário está disponivel.  Eu seleciono o campo consultor e digito o dia, após isso, clicando no botão, ele deveria trazer um retorno se esta livre ou ocupado, mas não esta fazendo.

Segue abaixo como era e como estou tentando fazer.

```
<a href="#" onClick="var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater('agenda_horario', '/php/clientes/carrega_horario_consultor.php?id_consultor='+document.forms[0].id_consultor.value+'&data_agendamento='+document.forms[0].data_agenda.value+'&id_franquia=<?=$id_franquia?>', {method: 'post', parameters: 'foo=bar'})" class="btn btn-confirma">Verificar hor&aacute;rios ocupados</a>
```

Estou tentando fazer

```
function carregaHorario() {



    var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater('agenda_horario', '/php/clientes/carrega_horario_consultor.php?id_consultor='+document.forms[0].id_consultor.value+'&data_agendamento='+document.forms[0].data_agenda.value+'&id_franquia=<?=$id_franquia?>',
    {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        parameters: 'foo=bar'
    })

}
```

Seguinte erro aparece

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM2462 a_controle_visitas1a.php:834)
```

Espero que possam me ajudar, obrigado.

Comment: Não deveria chamar a função **carregarHorario** em algum lugar, tipo no **onclick** do `button`??

Comment: Exato, no onclick, apenas chame a função `carregaHorario()`. E sobre o erro, está informando que você está puxando a propriedade .value de algo que não existe. No seu codigo essa propriedade aprece duas vezes, uma ligada a id_consultor e outra a data_agenda. Verifique se ambos os valores estão recebendo algum valor antes de serem chamados no ajax.

Comment: Opa, obrigado.
isso mesmo, estou usando um botão:

<a href="#" onClick="carregaHorario()" class="btn btn-confirma">Verificar hor&aacute;rios ocupados</a>

Como que eu poderia receber esse id_consultor e data_agenda ?